# Selecting TOP 1 Columns where duplicate exists and selecting all where no duplicate exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given the list of Names, Accounts and Positions I am trying to:

1. Select the 1st position where there are more than 1 records with the same Name and Account
2. If there is only 1 record with the Name and Account, then select details.

My current query looks like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM CTE cte1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT Name, OppName FROM CTE GROUP BY Name, OppName HAVING COUNT(Name)>1
) as cte2 
on cte2.Name = cte1.Name and cte2.OppName = cte1.OppName
ORDER BY cte1.OppName, cte1.Name
```

I have not posted the rest of the CTE query as it is way to long. 
However, this is only providing me with the results where the Name and Accounts are the same and the Positions are different.

I.E. If Oera worked at Christie's as a Sales Analyst and a Developer It would only Select the record where Oera worked at Christie's as a Developer.

How do I modify this query accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM CTE AS cte1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT Name, OppName,COUNT(Name) PARTITION BY (Name,OppName) cnt 
    FROM CTE
) AS cte2 
ON cte2.Name = cte1.Name and cte2.OppName = cte1.OppName
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY cte1.OppName, cte1.Name
```

Comment: Hmm. This returned 2 records:  Oeral, Chritie, Developer